# MySQL Select only the redundant rows and leave out the original rows

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
ID | NAME | TICKETNO
---------------------
 1 | Issa   | K1
 2 | kassim | K1
 3 | Said   | G5
 4 | Maya   | G5
 5 | Sara   | G5
 6 | Kesi   | J8
 7 | Ima    | J8
 8 | Fali   | O9
```

And I want to perform an MySQL query to select only the duplicates based on the colum `TICKETNO` and leave out the original rows and produce a table as follows

```
ID | NAME | TICKETNO
---------------------
 2 | kassim | K1
 4 | Maya   | G5
 5 | Sara   | G5
 7 | Ima    | J8
```

Can someone give a MySQL query to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE NOT ID IN ( 
    SELECT MIN(ID) FROM table_name GROUP BY TICKETNO
)
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b1941d/6/0